# Install R Ubuntu 17.10 [Broken Packages]

Tags: apt, 17.10, r

I am trying to install R on ubuntu 17.10

I have the following output;

```
$ sudo apt install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried the following:

```
$sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall
```

No output.

```
$sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$sudo aptitude full-upgrade
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

So for now I am stuck on how to go further..

Comment: Did you install on Server using these instructions : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2

Comment: Is this your first attempt to install R? Were there perhaps earlier attempts not cleaned up?

Comment: @Piloti yes I used that tutorial

Comment: @user535733 First time!

Comment: Did you modify the install instructions to add the *artful* repository, or did you blindly add the *xenial* repository in the instructions?

Comment: I guess I did it blindly! I will try it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the wrong rep:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
```

should be

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu artful/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first remove the wrong "xenial" repository by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
```

then install `r-base-core` by running:

```
sudo apt install r-base-core
```